# Как правильно вернуть ошибку в useMutation из обработчика api?

Tags: reactjs

Есть у меня api сервис, в нем реализован метод через который идут все запросы, типа:

```
async request({
    method,
    endpoint,
    data,
    params,
    headers,
    responseType,
    type = 'rest',
  }) {
       if (this.expireAt < Date.now() && !endpoint.includes('authorization')) {
        throw tokenExpired;
       }
    try {
      const req = await this.instanceTypes[type].request({
        method,
        url: endpoint,
        data,
        params,
        responseType: responseType || 'json',
        headers: {
          Authorization: this.token,
          ...headers,
        },
      });

      return req.data.data || req.data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      if (e.response?.status === 400 && e.response?.data?.code === 'WrongCredentials') {
        throw tokenExpired;
      }
      throw 'Api service not found';
    }
  }
```

Также есть хук, в котором используется useMutation и вызывается в определенный момент:

```
export const useGetAssetbox = () => {
  const { setIsTokenExpired } = useContext(Context);

  return useMutation((resourceName) => ApiService.requestRest({
    method: 'GET',
    endpoint: '/assetbox',
    params: { count: 100, resourceName }
  }), { onError: () => setIsTokenExpired(true) });
};
```

Все нормально отрабатывает, ошибка как бы обрабатывается (setIsTokenExpired(true), но помимо всего также появляется ошибка реакта поверх всего сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выбросить ошибку из моего апи сервиса, чтобы useMutation ее адекватно обработала и реакт не выкинул ошибку?
Пробовал вместо throw использовать return (чтобы вернуть ошибку в мутацию), но тогда мутация не идентифицирует этот ответ как ошибку и считает что запрос успешно выполнился. Как указать мутации что это error ответ, а не success?
throw, который перед try{} catch{} работает нормально. Если он выкидывает ошибку, то она нормально отрабатывается и react не выбрасывает уведомление о необработанной ошибке.